# c# How do i change the color of a specific textbox if it is empty?

Tags: c#, error-handling, colors, textbox

I am trying to change the color of an empty textbox, I have more than one textbox on this form and i wish to highlight the empty one when a user clicks submit. I have written the loop below which is in my btnSubmit function after checking if all the textbox have a value. Can anyone help in completing this loop for me??

```
foreach (Control txtbxs in this.Controls)
{
    if (txtbxs is TextBox)
    {
        var TBox = (TextBox)txtbxs;
        if (TBox.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            TBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

}
lblTopError.Text = "Please fill in the missing billing information";
pnlTopError.Visible = true;
```

Comment: The only thing I see here is you're changing the text color of an empty string, so you're not seeing the changes. What do you want to do?

Comment: @lc. I would like to change the edge of the textbox to red or somehow highlight the textbox since the user has left it empty... This is just to make it obvious to the user that this particular textbox is empty

Comment: Consider looking into [`ErrorProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) which will put a nice red exclamation-point icon next to the textbox with a tooltip explaining the error. (assuming you're in winforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since there aren't much textboxes in this form, i went the easy route and it worked, code bellow:

```
List<TextBox> boxes = new List<TextBox>();
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFname.Text))
{
    //highlightTextBox= txtFname;
    boxes.Add(txtFname);
}
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLname.Text))
{
    //highlightTextBox = txtLname;
    boxes.Add(txtLname);
}
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAddOne.Text))
{
    //highlightTextBox = txtAddOne;
    boxes.Add(txtAddOne);
}
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTown.Text))
{
    //highlightTextBox = txtTown;
    boxes.Add(txtTown);
}
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPostCode.Text))
{
    //highlightTextBox = txtPostCode;
    boxes.Add(txtPostCode);
}

foreach (var item in boxes)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Text))
    {
        item.BackColor = Color.Azure;
    }
}
lblTopError.Text = "Please fill in the missing billing information highlighted below";
pnlTopError.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

When your string is empty, changing the `ForeColor` will do nothing since you don't have Text to display in red.  Consider using `BackColor` and remember to have an event when text is entered to switch it back to the appropriate `BackColor`.

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you are trying to do, have  you considered using the error provider? this would help you to signal the user and prompt them to put in the information.

```
        errorProvider= new  System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider();
        errorProvider.BlinkRate = 1000;
        errorProvider.BlinkStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ErrorBlinkStyle.AlwaysBlink;


private void TextValidated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       var txtbox = Sender as TextBox;

        if(IsTextValid(txt))
        {
            // Clear the error, if any, in the error provider.
            errorProvider.SetError(txtbox, String.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            // Set the error if the name is not valid.
            errorProvider.SetError(txtbox, "Please fill in the missing billing information.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply any CSS you want like this:

```
TBox.Attributes.Add("style", "color: red; border: solid 1px #FC3000")
```

I would use this instead of:

```
TBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```